# Why is that i have to give argument while accessing print(dir(instance.function('hello'))) in our object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, oop, directory

lets consider the below mentioned example

```
class car():
    def car_type(self,car_name):
        return f'its an electric car and its a {car_name}'
instance=car()
print(instance.car_type('BMW'))
print(dir(car()))
print(dir(instance.car_type('hello')))
```

when you look closely to above mentioned code you will find that i have tried to access the directory of instance.car_type using this statement `print(dir(instance.car_type('hello')))`
and for instance if you remove the 'hello' from this statement it will thrown an error

```
TypeError: car_type() missing 1 required positional argument: 'car_name'
```

so in order to avoid this error i first tough it will take the same argument 'BMW' which i used earlier while calling the method of this class and error went away and when i tried changing 'BMW' argument with any random word for example 'hello' error went away but why that happened is still unknown to me.

and what surprised me most was that when i didn't gave any variable to my car_type function as mentioned below i was still able to access the directory of instance.car_type without any argument.

```
class car():
    def car_type(self):
        return 'its an electric car and its a'
instance=car()
print(instance.car_type())
print(dir(car()))
print(dir(instance.car_type()))
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `instance.car_type` will return a string if given a valid argument, and calling `dir()` on that string will return a list of the properties of string objects. But it is unclear what your objective is here.

Comment: Ohhk you are right that if i call print(dir(instance.car_type())) it will give me a list of directories in there . Only confusion i have here is that when i add variable car_name in >>>def car_type(self,car_name):     compiler is asking me to give argument  >>(dir(instance.car_type('hello')))  is this line too why is that ? and also if i change 'hello' to any random word line 'BMW'  it still works and gives me the list of directory but does this line need any parameter at 1st place when it doesn't affect our output .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give argument, compiler won't be able to compile code.

car_name parameter: def car_type(self,car_name) needs its argument in calling method: instance.car_type(???)

Comment: Yes its true that code wont work if i dont give argument while calling >>print(instance.car_type('BMW'))  but thats not my question my complaint is with the line >>print(dir(instance.car_type())) . so , in this line when i need directory why is  that compiler is asking me to give argument just like  >>(dir(instance.car_type('hello')))      or any other word  in replacement of 'BMW' why does this line need any argument at 1st place when it doesn't affect our output and also when there is no argument in line    
>>def car_type(self):  like (self,car_type) at that time dir dont need any argument